# How to play RMTP audio url in AVAudioPlayer Swift

Tags: swift, core-audio, avaudioplayer

I am looking to a great way to implement audio streaming using **RMTP** url in **AVAudioPlayer**.
Any ways to make this possible?  Or any suggestions?

Thanks

**UPDATE 1: Code included**

So here is the code:

```
let queue : dispatch_queue_t = dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0)
        dispatch_async(queue, { () -> Void in
            if let songData = NSData(contentsOfURL: url) {
                if let player = AVAudioPlayer(data: songData, error: nil) {
                    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), { () -> Void in
                        self.audioPlayer = player

                        self.audioPlayer!.delegate = self

                        if let startTime = startingTime {
                            self.audioPlayer?.currentTime = startTime
                        }

                        self.audioPlayer!.prepareToPlay()
                        self.audioPlayer!.play()
                        self.delegate?.mmPlayerManagerDelegate_playerStartedPlaying()
                    })
                }
            }
            else {
                dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), { () -> Void in
                    if appDelegate.bIsCurUserListener == false {
                        //=>    Call delegate
                        self.delegate?.mmPlayerManagerDelegate_prepareNextSongToPlay()
                    }
                })
            }
        })
```

And url is here:

- "rtmpLocation" : "rtmp://limelight-fmstream-42.musicnet.com/a4396/e1",
- "rtmpResource" : "mp4:/spl/114/602/883/spl_029.mp4?e=1435348059&h=8b4b2fd16683faa9bda9b4bab6d79705",

Comment: show the code and send the url

Comment: code included. Thanks Spynet

Comment: ok open the same link in iphone simulator  safari

Comment: if it is playing  then check this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24018327/what-does-an-exclamation-mark-mean-in-the-swift-language

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6042353/rtmp-stream-on-ios

Comment: @Spynet Safari cannot open the page.

Comment: so check the admin permission