# Facebook Live_videos RTMP streaming

Tags: ios, objective-c, facebook, facebook-sdk-4.0, live-video

I have successfully got the live video streaming URL from facebook.com using live_videos API. Now i am receiving a URL in the form of RTMP. I don't know how to play that because AVPlayer is unable to do that and i got the library VideoCore which was mentioned somewhere but somehow unable to build that. Anyone have idea?

I have tried https://github.com/jgh-/VideoCore this but unable to compile because of some CocoaPod issue

Comment: https://github.com/xiewei-wayne/rtmp-video-player-for-ios and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6042353/rtmp-stream-on-ios

Answer (score 0):

you can try to use [kxmovie](https://github.com/kolyvan/kxmovie)!
I hope that would be useful for you！

Answer (score 0):

Comparing to KxMovie, maybe [ijkplayer](https://github.com/Bilibili/ijkplayer) is more suitable for you and it still is developing actively. But KxMovie has more simple code to read. Both are based on FFmpeg. Hope it will help.